# Difference between visiblityOfAllElementsLocatedBy() and presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy() in selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests

What is difference between

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.cssSelector(".form-checkbox.notext")));
```

and

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.cssSelector(".form-checkbox.notext")));
```

Comment: A hidden (non-visible) element is still present (in the DOM): `<span style="display:none">Non-visible AND present!</span>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From docs:

https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html

```
public static ExpectedCondition<java.util.List<WebElement>> visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By locator)
```

An expectation for checking that **all elements present** on the web page that match the locator are visible. Visibility means that the elements are not only displayed but also have a height and width that is greater than 0.

```
public static ExpectedCondition<java.util.List<WebElement>> presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By locator)
```

An expectation for checking that there is **at least one element** present on a web page.

Answer (score 2):

**visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By locator)**

```
public static ExpectedCondition<java.util.List<WebElement>> visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By locator)
```

An expectation for checking that all elements present on the web page that match the locator are visible. Visibility means that the elements are not only displayed but also have a height and width that is greater than 0.

please find the help document here : https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy-org.openqa.selenium.By-

**presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy**

```
public static ExpectedCondition<java.util.List<WebElement>> presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By locator)
```

An expectation for checking that there is at least one element present on a web page.

Please find the Doc here : https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy-org.openqa.selenium.By-